i am get this error while build my electron-vite project
               workingDir=C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign

• Above command failed, retrying 3 more times
• downloading     url=https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder-binaries/releases/download/winCodeSign-2.6.0/winCodeSign-2.6.0.7z size=5.6 MB parts=1
• downloaded      url=https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder-binaries/releases/download/winCodeSign-2.6.0/winCodeSign-2.6.0.7z duration=2m29.064s
⨯ cannot execute  cause=exit status 2
out=
7-Zip (a) 21.07 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2021 Igor Pavlov : 2021-12-26
Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 5635384 bytes (5504 KiB)

Extracting archive: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\380855827.7z
--
Path = C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\380855827.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 5635384
Headers Size = 1492
Method = LZMA2:24m LZMA:20 BCJ2
Solid = +
Blocks = 2


Sub items Errors: 2

Archives with Errors: 1

Sub items Errors: 2

                errorOut=ERROR: Cannot create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\380855827\darwin\10.12\lib\libcrypto.dylib
ERROR: Cannot create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\380855827\darwin\10.12\lib\libssl.dylib

i am try to build it for windows

This exact problem has been exhibited in this question earlier today. Maybe you should file a bug report with the Electron Builder project?

There was also a similar question raised 10 days earlier, and it links to a GitHub Issue. Unfortunately, we can't flag them as duplicates. Lucas' seems like the best answer so far.

I just ran into the exact same issue with my Electron project, and I found a couple of solutions that worked for me.
Solution 1: Run as Administrator
First off, you can try running your terminal or VS Code as an administrator. This worked because the error you're seeing is related to a lack of privileges when creating symbolic links, which are needed during the build process.
Here's how you can do it:

Close your current terminal or VS Code session.
Right-click on the terminal (or VS Code) icon.
Select "Run as administrator."
Run the npm run build command again.

This might resolve the issue, but I found an even better solution that doesn't require you to run everything as an administrator every time.
Solution 2: Enable Developer Mode in Windows
This is the solution I used, and it worked like a charm. Enabling Developer Mode in Windows gives your system the necessary permissions to create symbolic links without needing elevated privileges every time.
Here’s how to enable it:

Open Settings in Windows.
Type in "Developer" and click > Use Developer Features.
Turn on Developer Mode.
Scroll down and click "PowerShell" dropdown
Switch on (It's basically agreeing to run scripts without signing)

After doing this, I was able to build my project without any issues and I didn't have to run my terminal as admin. It's a more permanent fix, so you don't have to worry about running things as an administrator ever in the future.
Hopefully, one of these solutions works for you!

working Workaround Solution without need of Admin Rights
is documented in
https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/8149 Failed to create dylib symbolic link on Windows
as a working workaround. Thanks to renkei:
There is maybe a better workaround available:
Download the winCodeSign.7z package manually. You can use the same URL as electron-builder is using:
https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder-binaries/releases/download/winCodeSign-2.6.0/winCodeSign-2.6.0.7z
Then extract the archive to the requested location (I've used 7-Zip 23.01 for Windows) so that you have this folder on your machine:
C:\Users<YourUserName>\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\winCodeSign-2.6.0\
That's it. I got no errors during extraction. Once the folder exists the download and extraction of the 7z file is skipped during the electron-builder run.
Pro:
You don't need admin rights
You can use the latest version of electron-builder
You need to do this only once as preparation step, also easy to realize in a CI environment

Con
You have to do it as long as this issue is not fixed.

